# Definition of Inner Product boolean function

Tags: functions

I want to define a boolean function $f: \{-1,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ which gives the inner product in the given range and defined as :
$$f(x_1,x_2,.......,x_n,x_{n+1},....,x_{2n})= x_1x_{n+1}+x_2x_{n+2}+.....+x_nx_{2n}$$
Here, value of $x_1x_{n+1}+x_2x_{n+2}+.....+x_nx_{2n}$ should be either $+1$ or $-1$, So it means I have to use some operation to get values as $\{\pm 1\}$ but I am not getting what operation should I have to do so that it will give values either $+1$ or $-1$.
For example, if we have $n=2$ then for $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (1,1,1,1)$, So, $f(1,1,1,1)= 2$. Now, which operation should I have to perform so that value 2 will be converted to $+1$ or $-1$.
One way I am thinking about to do the mapping from $\mathbb{F}_2^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ and then encode it as $0 \mapsto 1$ and $1 \mapsto -1$ like for $n=1$ in truth table, I can replace $f(0,0)=0$ to $f(1,1)=1$ and $f(1,1)=1$ to  $f(-1,-1)=-1$ etc.
If I have a function $g: \mathbb{F}_2^{2n} \rightarrow \{-1,1 \}$ then I can define the inner product mod 2 boolean function as
$$g(x_1,x_2,.....,x_n,y_1,y_2,....,y_n) = (-1)^{x.y}$$
where $x.y$ is the dot product of $x=(x_1,x_2,....,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,....,y_n)$ in vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n.$
But how to define it on $f: \{-1,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$. If I do the same mapping as defined for $\mathbb{F}_2^{2n} \rightarrow \{-1,1 \}$ i.e. $(-1)^{x.y}$ then for $n=2$, I am getting all the values of $+1$ and for $n=3$, it gives $-1$. Here, $(-1)^{odd}=-1$ and $(-1)^{even}=+1$  So, I can use this mapping i.e.$(-1)^{x.y}$  but Is there any other way to define mapping for $f$ because I have to find the Fourier expansion of inner product boolean function which is defined on $\{-1,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}.$
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n=1$ is trivial and uninformative. So look at the case for $n=2$.

By commutivity of addition, you want

1. $f(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2) = f(x_2, x_1, y_2, y_1)$

By distributivity of multiplication over addition, you want

2. $f(x_1, x_2, -y_1, -y_2) = -f(x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)$

Here in lies a problem.

- By 1, $f(1,1,1,-1) = f(1,1,-1,1)$
- By 2, $f(1,1,1,-1) = -f(1,1,-1,1)$

So $f(1,1,1,-1) = -f(1,1,1,-1)$. But the only values allowed are $1$ and $-1$, neither of which are its own opposite.

You can't do this without either giving up commutivity of addition, or distributivity.